# How to pass response json from android to HTML using android HTML Webview?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to display response json in android HTML Webview,while clicking the button it will invoke the Activity and loads the asset URL but load() returns null as the responseJsonObject,because before the completion of getData() load() returns responseJsonObject as null.By setting break points and debugging the code step by step it's giving the expected result,I understood it's because of asynchronous call,don't have clear picture of how to handle this kind of invocation.

Anyone please guide me to handle this invocation?.

Note:I have used thread also like,

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public JSONObject load() throws JSONException {
        Log.d("RESPONSE>>", "WEBCONNECTOR");
        Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                 response = getData();//response also declared as global variable
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
        if (response != null)
            return responseJsonObject;
        else {
            return new JSONObject("{'Message':'No Data Found!.'}");
        }
    }
```

**Activity.java**

```
    public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
     private JSONObject responseJsonObject = null;
    Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_response_display);
        final WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String webConnector = "webConnector";
        String toaster = "toaster";
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, webConnector);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, toaster);
        String folder_path = "file:/android_asset/";
        String fileName = "sample.html";
        String file = folder_path + fileName;
        webView.loadUrl(file);
        }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public JSONObject load(){
    getData();
    return responseJsonObject;
    }
  @JavascriptInterface
    public void checkData(JSONObject data) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "hello" + data.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

   public void getData(){
   //REST SERVICE INVOCATION
   responseJsonObject=result.asJSONObject();
}
}
```

**activity_response_display.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/webView">
        </WebView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Sample.html**

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loader(){
        var responseJSON=window.webConnector.load();
        toaster.checkData(responseJSON);
        document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML=responseJSON;
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="loader()">
    <p id="hello">result:</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Where/how do you execute your `delay` Runnable?

Comment: If you want to load `html` text then use `webView.loadData(yourData, "text/html", "UTF-8");`

Comment: okay,can u tell me is there any way to get the loaded response data in html? @ADM

Comment: while invoking load from html only the delay thread can be executed,pls correct me if I am wrong @ Diego